# Redirect output to stdout and filter version to file

Tags: bash, macos, grep, pipe, tee

I've been messing around with grep/tee and pipes but cannot find a working command to achieve this in a bash script I'm writing on Mac.

The following command does the reverse of what I want (output.log contains all lines and stdout contains only lines which were grepped with filterMeOut). Anyone know how I can only filter the output.log file? Preferably without process substitution because I'm on a mac with shell v3 which does not support that functionality.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec App 2>&1 | tee output.log | grep 'filterMeOut'
```

Comment: Perhaps `App 2>&1 | tee >(grep 'filterMeOut' >output.log)`

Comment: Than I always seem to get this error "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Comment: Are you sure your shell is `bash` ?

Comment: hmm I think so. I added the 'header' to the post. Also the extension of the file is .sh and is ran on a macintosch

Comment: Using GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21)

Comment: I'm not familiar with macOS. You may want to open a new question asking why it doesn't work, specifying the error message you got and adding `macos` tag as well. My suggestion's working on my Linux platform.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Thanks, I think this doesn't work on macos because it only ships bash v3.2. Now only if updating bash on mac was easy... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451684/update-bash-in-shell-scripts-on-macos

Answer (score 0):

I understand your goal is print all lines on stdout and filtered lines in a file.

Sometime, I use this function:

```bash
function exec_ternary () {
    local -r CMD_EXEC_TERNARY="$1"
    shift
    local -r CMD_EXEC_STDOUT="$1"
    shift
    local -r CMD_EXEC_STDERR="$1"
    shift
    {
        {
              (${CMD_EXEC_TERNARY} "${@}") 3>&- \
            | (${CMD_EXEC_STDOUT}  "${@}") 2>&3 3>&-
        } 2>&1 >&4 4>&- \
          |   (${CMD_EXEC_STDERR}  "${@}") 3>&- 4>&-
    } 3>&2 4>&1
}
```

Notes:

- It's useful to exec different commands on stdout and on stderr.
- This code is freely inspired from https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial#an_example

1. Define the first argument, the command to execute:

```bash
function func_stdin () {
  App 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr
}
```

Note:

- `tee /dev/stderr` command permit to put the same `App` output on stdin and stderr outputs.

2. Define the second argument, the command on stdout:

```bash
function func_stdout () {
  cat
}
```

Note:

- Simply print stdin on stdout!

3. Define the third argument, the command on stderr:

```bash
function func_stderr () {
  grep 'filterMeOut' > 'output.log'
}
```

Note:

- `grep` filter result to `output.log`I understand your goal is print all lines on stdout and filtered lines in a file.

`exec_ternary` command used like this:

```bash
exec_ternary func_stdin func_stdout func_stderr
```